# Display data from database inside <table> using wordpress $wpdb insdie a shortcode

Tags: php, html, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

The code below prints into one block without formatting. Given that shortcodes already run php am I specifying the html properly? It doesnt feel like it since the HTML portion doesnt seem to be working for me. It jsut outputs as an entire block. (see picture)

```
   function trying_2() {
    '
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
     <th>name</th>
     <th>partysize</th>
     <th>phonenumber</th>
    </tr>';

   
 global $wpdb;

// sending query
 $result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT *  FROM table_name");
    foreach ( $result as $print )   {

      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>' . $print->name.'</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $print->partysize.'</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $print->phonenumber.'</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $print->emailaddress.'</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $print->Time_stamp.'</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $print->currentstatus.'</td>';
    '</tr>';
    }
 '</table>';
}

add_shortcode('tryin', 'trying_2');
```

[image: picture of what this prints]

Comment: "*...the HTML portion doesnt seem to be working for me.*" What exactly do you mean by not working - is it displaying an error, showing a blank screen, not being displayed correctly, not being display at all? Have you checked the browsers element inspector to see what HTML (if any) is being generated on the page? If this is the function you're using, your HTML isn't even being output at the beginning so that definitely will cause problems.

Comment: "The code below prints into one block without formatting. " >>>If this is the function you're using, your HTML isn't even being output at the beginning so that definitely will cause problems. Then what would be the proper way?

Comment: "*Then what would be the proper way?*" - output the first HTML block of code so you have valid HTML

Comment: Just did. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not formatting the `HTML` / `table` correctly hence why you are getting everything printed in one line on your page in wordpress.

You do **not** need to echo each `td` separately. You just to wrap have one `variable` define for to be `echoed` and in your `function` and just use and you just need to concatenate the loop data to that variable.

Just **paste** this below `code` in your active theme `functions.php` file and then call your short code `[tryin]` in a page. (Code tested and works)

```
function trying_2() {

    global $wpdb;
    
    $results = '<table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>partysize</th>
                    <th>phonenumber</th>
                    <th>emailaddress</th>
                    <th>Time_stamp</th>
                    <th>currentstatus</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>';

        // sending query
        $WPQuery = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM table_name");
            foreach ( $WPQuery as $print )   {
                $results .= "<tr>
                            <td>$print->name</td>
                            <td>$print->partysize</td>
                            <td>$print->phonenumber</td>
                            <td>$print->emailaddress</td>
                            <td>$print->Time_stamp</td>
                            <td>$print->currentstatus</td>
                        </tr>";
                    }
                $results .= "</tbody>
    </table>";
    //Print results
    echo $results;
}

add_shortcode('tryin', 'trying_2');
```